# Mysql multiple check and multiple update queries

Tags: mysql, php

i have question about checking and updating.
The problem is that i create a very basic mysql select and update , and
two times in day i get file where php reads it. In that file have more than 14k-60k records. Database checks if that id exists then make update for 2 columns but if that record doesnt exist then insert.

```
foreach($product_list as $id => $var) {if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT product_id FROM products WHERE product_id = $id")) == 0) { // insert}else{//update}}
```

problem is that, that script is taking very much resources and execute very long.
Is it possible to speed up this process or somehow make it in few queries? I understand that there is going more than 60k queries in this code.
P.s this is simple example with mysql but in real code im using PDO but system is like the same as this code.

Comment: You could use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to avoid sending 2 queries for each row. Combine that with inserting multiple rows per statement (100, 1000 rows per statement or even all 60K in one) and you'll eliminate the overhead.

Comment: But how much i understand First i need to make insert, because i have few days when i receive file without any new records.

Comment: I think i find out about lot of updates but i really dont know if its correct by in one query send CASE. for example UPDATE products SET Price = CASE product_id
  WHEN 1 THEN 20.00
  ELSE barcode
  END;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest little more longer method, but work fine:

1. **Load** file into table, for example TableB (original in this case TableA), TableB has only PK - id
2. **Update** - before INSERT

   ```
   UPDATE TableA t1 INNER JOIN TableB t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
   ```
3. **Insert**

   ```
   INSERT INTO TableA 
   SELECT * 
   FROM TableB t1 
   WHERE NOT EXISTS 
         (SELECT id FROM TableA t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
   ```

I prefer this way, because:

- it fast
- it flexible - steps in-dependent and logic for UPDATE/INSERT could be
  changed separately

Comment: Sounds interesting. Im gonna try it thank you for answer :)